# .htaccess rewrite url with get parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite something like that.

```
http://127.0.0.1/code1/code2/get?a=8&q=7
```

code1 and code2 is changing

```
http://127.0.0.1/get.php?c1=code1&c2=code2&a=8&q=7
```

I have tried much things such as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^get\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/get?(.*)$ /get.php?c1=$1&c2=$2&$3 [L]
```

The code1 and code2 working but the get not.

================
I have a test php file like this

```
<?php
echo $_GET['c1']."<br>";
echo $_GET['c2']."<br>";
echo $_GET['a']."<br>";
echo $_GET['q']."<br>";
?>
```

And that is what I receive.

```
code1
code2
```

Comment: _"The code1 and code2 working but the get not."_ - of course not, because RewriteRule matches against the _path_ component of the URL, and not the query string. If you wanted to match or capture something in the latter - you need to do so using a RewriteCond.

Comment: But if you just want to merge the original query string with the newly created one - use the `QSA` flag.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/get$ get.php?c1=$1&c2=$2 [L]
```

Then you will get the values of `c1` and `c2`.
to get the rest of your values

```
$katorymnd_uxqn  = explode("&", explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1] );
print_r($katorymnd_uxqn);
```

Giving you array of your remaining values

```
Array ( [0] => a=8 [1] => q=7 );
```

Your page `get.php` code should look like this

```
echo $_GET['c1']."<br>";
echo $_GET['c2']."<br>";


$katorymnd_uxqn  = explode("&", explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1] );

$katorymnd_ldba = array();
$katorymnd_ldba[] = $katorymnd_uxqn;

print explode('=', $katorymnd_ldba[0][0], 2)[1]."<br>";
print  explode('=', $katorymnd_ldba[0][1], 2)[1]."<br>";
```

Now you get all the values as expected.

```
code1
code2
8
7
```